# Split the child records of xml into individual messages in activeMQ in jboss fuse

Tags: jboss, routes, apache-camel, redhat, jbossfuse

This is a jboss fuse project

i have this scenario where a  file has 1 XML with multiple child records. i need to Split the child records and use XSLT to convert it to multiple XML
 .
SAMPLE XML ORDER (INPUT):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
  
</catalog>
```

i have this XSLT :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <!-- TODO: Auto-generated template -->
  <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
            <xsl:result-document href="file{position()}.xml">
                <document>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current()"/>
                </document>
            </xsl:result-document>
            
          
        </xsl:for-each>
        
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

BLUEPRINT.xml(CAMEL ROUTE)

```html
 <route id="_route1">
            <from id="_from1" uri="file:work/in"/>
            <log id="_log1" message="${body}"/>
            <loop id="_loop1">
                <xpath>count(/catalog/cd)</xpath>
                <to id="_to1" uri="xslt:file:C:\Users\a638030\workspace\splitxml\data\order1.xsl"/>
                <log id="_log2" message="${body}"/>
            </loop>
        </route>
```

when i run this route it says error AS BELOW :

```html
[xt) thread #2 - file://work/in] _route1                        INFO  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
  
</catalog>


[xt) thread #2 - file://work/in] XPathBuilder                   INFO  Created default XPathFactory com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathFactoryImpl@4b4289ed
[xt) thread #2 - file://work/in] DefaultErrorHandler            ERROR Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-MC0WKB0C-60902-1513777570783-0-1 on ExchangeId: ID-MC0WKB0C-60902-1513777570783-0-2). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.builder.xml.InvalidXPathExpression: Invalid xpath: count(/catalog/cd). Reason: javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPathException: Can not convert #NUMBER to a NodeList!

Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[_route1           ] [_route1           ] [file://work/in                                                                ] [       270]
[_route1           ] [_log1             ] [log                                                                           ] [         7]
[_route1           ] [_loop1            ] [loop[xpath{XPath: count(/catalog/cd)}]                                        ] [       224]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
org.apache.camel.builder.xml.InvalidXPathExpression: Invalid xpath: count(/catalog/cd). Reason: javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPathException: Can not convert #NUMBER to a NodeList!
 at org.apache.camel.builder.xml.XPathBuilder.doInEvaluateAs(XPathBuilder.java:916)
 at org.apache.camel.builder.xml.XPathBuilder.evaluateAs(XPathBuilder.java:780)
 at org.apache.camel.builder.xml.XPathBuilder.evaluate(XPathBuilder.java:750)
 at org.apache.camel.builder.xml.XPathBuilder.evaluate(XPathBuilder.java:165)
 at org.apache.camel.processor.LoopProcessor.process(LoopProcessor.java:64)
 at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
 at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:468)
 at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:196)
 at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)
 at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
 at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:196)
 at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:454)
 at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:226)
 at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:190)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:175)
 at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:102)
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
 at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
 at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPathException: Can not convert #NUMBER to a NodeList!
 at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.evaluate(XPathExpressionImpl.java:204)
 at org.apache.camel.builder.xml.XPathBuilder.doInEvaluateAs(XPathBuilder.java:898)
 ... 22 more
Caused by: com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPathException: Can not convert #NUMBER to a NodeList!
 at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.objects.XObject.error(XObject.java:711)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.objects.XObject.nodelist(XObject.java:457)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.getResultAsType(XPathExpressionImpl.java:364)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.eval(XPathExpressionImpl.java:110)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.evaluate(XPathExpressionImpl.java:191)
 ... 23 more
```

IN THIS  IT FIRSE LOGS THE XML FILE WHICH I PROVIDE THE INPUT AND THEN IT GIVES ERROR FOR THE XPATH EXPRESSION IN THE LOOP ROUTE.

SO can you help me with this or is there some other approach for this scenario ?

Scenario: i have this scenario where a  file has 1 XML with multiple child records. i need to Split the child records and use XSLT to convert it to multiple XML (in JBOSS FUSE )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankyou for your help @ noMad17  .

(BLUEPRINT.XML)Route with ActiveMQ  :

```html
   <route id="_route1">
            <from id="_from1" uri="file:work/in"/>
            <log id="_log1" message="${body}"/>
            <split id="_split1">
                <xpath>/catalog/cd</xpath>
                <log id="_log3" message="split data :  ${body}"/>
                <to id="_to1" uri="xslt:file:C:\Users\a638030\workspace\Scenario5\data\order.xsl"/>
                <log id="_log2" message="After XSLT : ${body}"/>
                <to id="_to2" pattern="InOnly" uri="activemq:queue:OrderDetails"/>
            </split>
        </route>
```

XML INPUT:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd  >
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
  
</catalog>
```

XSLT:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:element name="catalog">
   <xsl:element name="cd">
    <xsl:copy-of select="/*[local-name()='cd']/*"/>
   </xsl:element>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output MSG IN ACTIVEMQ :

```html
Message 1 :

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><catalog><cd><title>Empire Burlesque</title><artist>Bob Dylan</artist><country>USA</country><company>Columbia</company><price>10.90</price><year>1985</year></cd></catalog>

Message 2: 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><catalog><cd><title>Hide your heart</title><artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist><country>UK</country><company>CBS Records</company><price>9.90</price><year>1988</year></cd></catalog>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change this:

```
        <loop id="_loop1">
            <xpath>count(/catalog/cd)</xpath>
            <to id="_to1" uri="xslt:file:C:\Users\a638030\workspace\splitxml\data\order1.xsl"/>
            <log id="_log2" message="${body}"/>
        </loop>
```

Into this:

```
        <split id="_split1">
            <xpath>/catalog/cd</xpath>
            <to id="_to1" uri="xslt:file:C:\Users\a638030\workspace\splitxml\data\order1.xsl"/>
            <log id="_log2" message="${body}"/>
        </split>
```

When doing this you will get one exchange per cd-element and as such you'll have to change your XSLT accordingly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:param name="CamelSplitIndex" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:result-document href="file$CamelSplitIndex.xml">
            <document>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </document>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I suggest you take a look at the [Splitter EIP](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html)

Comment: Correct i did this(i.e using splitter ) but then how will it generate individual file for each child node as a message in ActiveMQ using XSLT. it gives error for <xsl:result-document href in XSLT

Comment: If it is necessary for you to have the XSLT create a numbered file you could perhaps use the `CamelSplitIndex`. I'll edit my answer to give an example.

Comment: Actually, now that I read about the `result-document` it says that `href` specifies a location where the file will be written. Is the purpose to send each document to ActiveMQ, or do you actually want to create files?

Comment: initially i thought of file but now i want in  activeMQ mesaage as i will be sendind xml uaing activeMQ only. also for learning purpose can you give for file method also

Comment: i tried that updated xslt , but still it gives the same error of result-documents as below :    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported XSL element 'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform:result-document'
 at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:746)

Comment: I'll update my answer a bit later today. But that error is because you're trying to use XSLT 2.0 functions, but Xalan only supports 1.0. Add this to your uri: `?transformerFactoryClass=net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl` and the `camel-saxon` dependency to your pom.

Comment: thankyou .@ noMad17 . can you have a look at my answer and give a tick if it looks good.